# First-order formulas with exponentially large models

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

The *separated fragment* of First-Order Logic (FOL) is the sublanguage of FOL in which no atomic sub-formula $A(\ldots,x,\ldots,y,\ldots)$ is such that $x$ is bound by and existential quantifier and $y$ is bound by a universal quantifier.

Such fragment is defined and shown decidable in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08999) paper. The authors prove that the fragment has the finite model property, giving also a bound to the size of models which is exponential in the size of the formula.

My question is to find an example of a sentence of the separated fragment with $n$ bound variables whose models are at least of size, say, $2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the language with $n$ unary predicates $\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$. Let $\varphi_i(x,y)$ be the formula $$\lnot (P_i(x)\leftrightarrow P_i(y)) \land \bigwedge_{j\neq i} (P_j(x)\leftrightarrow P_j(y)).$$
This formula asserts that $x$ and $y$ disagree on the truth of $P_i$ but agree on the truth of each other $P_j$. Now consider the sentence $\psi$: $$(\exists z\,(z = z)) \land \bigwedge_{i=1}^n \forall x\, \exists y\, \varphi_i(x,y).$$

For any model $M$ of $\psi$ and any subset $X\subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$, $M$ must contain an element satisfying $P_i$ for all $i\in X$ and $\lnot P_i$ for all $i\notin X$. Indeed, $M$ is nonempty, and starting from any element, you can find elements satisfying any given set of the $P_i$ by applying the clauses $\forall x\, \exists y\, \varphi_i(x,y)$ one at a time to find an element which disagrees about the truth value of a single $P_i$. So $|M| \geq 2^n$.

The length of $\varphi_i$ is $O(n)$, and the length of $\psi$ is $O(n^2)$. So letting $\ell$ be the length of $\psi$, the size of $M$ is $O(2^\ell)$.

This answers the question you asked (though I prefer to measure the complexity of a formula by its length, instead of the number of bound variables). But the bound given in the paper (Theorem 17) is *$n$-fold exponential* in the length of the formula, where $n$ is the number of alternations of quantifier blocks in prenex normal form. This means $O(2^{2^{\dots ^\ell}})$ where the tower of exponentials has height $n$. I expect coming up with a family of sentences exhibiting that this bound is tight would be much more difficult. And it seems the authors think it might not be tight. They write "Our *current* upper bound on the size of small models is non-elementary in the length of the formula" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $2n$ one-place predicate symbols $B_{1,0}, \ldots, B_{n,0}$ and $B_{1,1}, \ldots, B_{n,1}$. The intended meaning of $B_{i,j}(x)$ is ``the binary string $x$ has a bit of value $j$ in position $i$. For convenience bits are numbered from right to left.

There exists a string made of $n$ zerores:

1. $(\exists x) \bigwedge_{i=1}^n B_{i,0}(x)$

Each bit of every string contains either a zero or a one but not both:

2. $(\forall x)(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n B_{i,0}(x) \leftrightarrow \neg B_{i,1}(x))$

Define 
$$
\varphi_{k}(x) \equiv 
\begin{cases}
B_{1,0}(x) & \text{if } k = 1 \\
B_{k,0}(x) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=1}^{k-1} B_{i,1}(x) & \text{if } 1 < k \leq n 
\end{cases}
$$

The formula $\varphi_{k}(x)$ should be read as ``the $k$-th bit of the string $x$ is 0 and all the bits to its right are 1".

Define 
$$
\zeta_{k}(x) \equiv 
\begin{cases}
B_{1,1}(x) & \text{if } k = 1 \\
B_{k,1}(x) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=1}^{k-1} B_{i,0}(x) & \text{if } 1 < k \leq n 
\end{cases}
$$

The formula $\zeta_{k}(x)$ should be read as ``the $k$-th bit of the string $x$ is 1 and all the bits to its right are 0".

Define 
$$
\psi_{s,t}(x,y) \equiv 
\begin{cases}
\bigwedge_{i=s}^{t} B_{i,0}(x)\leftrightarrow B_{i,0}(y) & \text{if } s \leq t \\
\top & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The formula $\psi_{s,t}(x,y)$ should be read as ``the bits from position $s$ to position $t$ included of the strings $x$ and $y$ coincide".

For every binary string $x$ there exists the binary string $y = x +1$:

3. $\bigwedge_{k=1}^n (\forall x)(\varphi_{k}(x) \to (\exists y)\zeta_{k}(x) \wedge \psi_{k+1,n}(x,y) )$

The conjunction of formulas 1, 2, and 3 should force a model to contain all $2^n$ binary strings of bits.

Maybe this construction can be ``nested" forcing models to be sets of binary strings each one of length  ${2^n}$ but right now I don't know how to keep a polynomially sized vocabulary.